# smtp problem for outlook 365 for navision 2013,2016

Tags: navision

smtp outlook 365 mail issue in Navision 2013 and 2016 above version

problem in smtp outlook 365 mail issue in Navision 2013 and 2016 above version
smtp 375 error shown in mail setup sale order  and grn not working because of smtp error

Answer (score 0):

1. remove authenticater in  sender mail
2. update the SMTP address to smtp-legacy.office365.com and enable legacy TLS clients in the Exchange Admin Center -> Settings -> Mail flow 'Turn on use of legacy TLS clients.